# working with ebextensions in aws

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, amazon-web-services, url-rewriting, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am working with AWS elastic beanstalk and since I can't modify the `httdp conf` file to `AllowOverride All` I was suggested to work with `ebextensions`:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers.html
Hence, I have created an .ebextensions folder, and within it a setup.config file with the following command:

```
container_commands:
    01_setup_apache:
        command: "cp .ebextensions/enable_mod_rewrite.conf /etc/httpd/conf.d/enable_mod_rewrite.conf"
```

I am not even sure if this is the proper command to enable mod rewrite, but I get the following error while trying to upload the instance:

```
[Instance: i-80bbbd77] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: cp: cannot stat '.ebextensions/enable_mod_rewrite.conf': No such file or directory. container_command 01_setup_apache in .ebextensions/setup.config failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't copy from ".ebextensions/enable_mod_rewrite.conf" because that relative path will not be valid from the init script. Using absolute paths may work, but there i'd suggest you fetch from S3 instead:

```
container_commands:
    01_setup_apache:
        command: "aws s3 cp s3://[my-ebextensions-bucket]/enable_mod_rewrite.conf /etc/httpd/conf.d/enable_mod_rewrite.conf"
```

But if you need complex changes to your instance, it may be a better option to run a docker container instead: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker.html

Comment: thanks for the answer, where I would found what [my-exbension-bucket] is? thanks. Without doing complex changes, should this be sufficient to get htaccess to work?

Comment: you'd need to create and name that S3 bucket... and yes, that should work, but always check the cloud-init and eb logs in /var/log/ if something does not.

Comment: thanks for your response. so lets assume that the name is testWork for the new s3 bucket named would it be aws s3 cp s3://testWork/enable_mod_rewrite.conf... how would i link this s3 bucket that instance. do i assume it will be automaticalyl link upon upload?

Comment: I unfortunatetly receive the following error while trying to do the above [Instance: i-80bbbd77] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: A client error (404) occurred when calling the HeadObject operation: Key "enable_mod_rewrite.conf" does not exist Completed 1 part(s) with ... file(s) remaining. container_command 01_setup_apache in .ebextensions/setup.config failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.